# Django OneToOneField related name works for one Model but not another

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-one

I have a project with common store-like functionality of Q&As and Reviews for each Item. The app is more complex than just this, but this is the boiled down crux of the issue. Here is the basic model and apps setup:

```
# Q&As App
Class Question(models.Model):
    ...

# Reviews App
Class Review(models.Model):
    ...

# Items App
Class Item(models.Model):
    ...

Class ItemQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question, related_name='item_question')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='questions')
    ...

Class ItemReview(models.Model):
    review = models.OneToOneField(Review, related_name='item_review')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='reviews')
    ...
```

This issue comes when using the reverse look ups:

```
Question().item_question # Raises Question.item_question.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Question has no item_question
Review().item_review # Returns ComponentReview instance
```

detailed stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 415, in __get__                                                                                        
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
Question.item_question.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Question has no item_question
```

I'm not interested in design decision alternatives or anything like that, but more trying to understand why this is happening. Looking at the model setup and the migration files, everything seems identical in terms of code implementation, so why does one reverse lookup work and not the other? How can I get both to work?

Thanks!

Django Version 2.2

Comment: A `OneToOneField` means that each `ItemReview` for example is linked to *one* `Review` object and that that `Review` object is *unique*. Contrary to popular belief, it does *not* mean that each `Review` object has one `ItemReview` object.

Comment: In the case the reverse thus does not exists, fetching the attribute results in a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExists` (subclass of `AttributeError`, and `ObjectDoesNotExists` error).

Comment: I don't understand why I can't access that related name from python.